# Usar 2 correos para Git

Tags: git, github, email

estoy tratando de usar mi propia cuenta de correo personal en un directorio concreto para un proyecto. No obstante, por temas de la universidad, sin querer configuré mi usuario con el correo de la universidad con el parámetro --global, y a la hora de poner, en un directorio concreto:

```
git config user.name "______"
```

me sale este mensaje

```
fatal: not in a git directory
```

(También me pasa con user.email)

¿Sería posible asociar de alguna forma el correo de la universidad a un directorio concreto, y mi correo personal a otro? No sé si llegaría a ser bastante complejo.

Comment: El error que te da es porque cuando usas el comando `git` debes estar en una carpeta que sea un repositorio (es decir, que haya sido inicializada con `git init` o creada con un `git clone`, en definitiva, que tenga una subcarpeta oculta llamada `.git`)

Answer (score 1):

Si no estas en un repo, podrías configurar una propiedad *global*, pero git no lo va a adivinar, tienes que usar `--global`. Y, como dice @abulafia en su comentario, propiedades *no* globales solo son configutables en un repositorio. Dentro de un repositorio, *no* puedes tener diferentes configuraciones *de las que se manejan con `git config`*. Lo que se maneje con `.attributes` si es mucho más flexible porque se pueden colocar diferentes archivos de atributos por directorio.